# Accessing javascript object property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects called user. So when I do `console.log(user[0]);`
I get an output like : `Object {activityId: "2", id: "1", activityDt: "01/15/2016"}`

So then I decided to store the user[0] in a seprate object.

```
var p = user[0];
```

Now finally I want to get the activityId of the object so I do

```
console.log(p.activityId);
```

But nothing gets printed and I get an error. Please suggest.

My code

```
 mainFactory.getUser()
  .success(function(usersData) {
      $scope.userData = usersData;

      // Determine which events we will show (removce certain events)

      var userActivity = [];
      angular.forEach($scope.userData, function (user, index){

        // console.log(user.length);

        //for(var i = 0; i<user.length; i++){
        //   console.log(user[i]);
        // }

        // console.log(user[0]);
        var p = user[0];
        console.log(p.activityId);

        // for (var key in p) {
        //   alert(p[key]);
        // }




      });
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      console.log('Error: ' + err);
    });
```

Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'activityId' of undefined
    at main.controller.js:54
    at Object.forEach (angular.js:334)
    at main.controller.js:44
    at angular.js:9433
    at processQueue (angular.js:13318)
    at angular.js:13334
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:14570)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:14386)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:14675)
    at done (angular.js:9725)
```

Comment: What do you get if you try `console.log(p)`?

Comment: Post more code, because that should work if things really are exactly as you describe. Are those lines of code one after the other in the program, or are they separated somehow?

Comment: @JanTojnar if i do console.log(p); i get same result as console.log(user[0]);

Comment: I've run those lines of code myself, and they do indeed work. We will need to see much more details of the code to help with this. Posting the error message would also be helpful.

Comment: @millerbr i have posted error , i don't know why someone wants  to close my question. that is so strange.

Comment: Ok, so from your error, I can tell that `p` is not storing your object at the time you try to console log it. To debug this, I'll need to see more of the code.

Comment: @user1010101 I didn't vote to close (yet), but the stated reason for that close vote is correct - the code, as shown, doesn't demonstrate the bug. The cause of the problem isn't here, and we are not psychic. *"Questions seeking debugging help... must include... the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. "

Comment: @millerbr i have posted my code

Comment: @PaulRoub i am sorry, i have posted code now if this makes it better please let me know

Comment: @Akis_Tfs yeah anything should work but i get error wether it is id or activityId

Comment: inside angular.forEach, u are using  var p = user[0];, it should be         
var p = user;

Comment: @VishalRajole read my comment under Simon's answer.

Comment: @user1010101, what gives `console.log(user instanceof Array)` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i get false

Comment: @user1010101, it means that `user` is not a regular array. Show me `console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(user))`

Answer (score 2):

once you have used `forEach`, you are getting individual elements of `$scope.userData`. Calling `users` as though an array will not work and `user[0]` will be undefined, as reported by your error

```
angular.forEach($scope.userData, function (user, index){
    var p = user;
    console.log(p.activityId);
```

Comment: Just a question though, basically i want to print id or say activityId of each individual how do i do that because doing var p = user is storing all the objects i think.

Comment: I just tried that -> console.log(p.activityId); i get undefined.

Comment: you mean do console.log(user) ?

Comment: [Object, Object, Object] is what i get when i do console.log(user)

Comment: So you assert `console.log(user[0]);` gives `Object {activityId: "2", id: "1", activityDt: "01/15/2016"}` inside the `forEach` loop?